# Can't use Radeon GPU to render in cycles (R9 270)

Tags: rendering, gpu

In the settings I can't choose another device to render other than the CPU.

[image: Can't select the GPU.]

According to the blender wiki the GPUs "with a GCN Architecture superior or equal to 2.0 are supported".

[image: Blender wiki]

And as I understand my GPU (R9 270) should be supported, according to this table from wikipedia(and has GCN 2.0 and up):
[image: Wikipedia table]

Or am I wrong and my GPU isn't actually supported? :(

**GPU**:    R9 270 (latest drivers)

**OpenCL version**: 22.19

**Blender version**: 2.79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R9 270 is actually GCN 1.0 architecture and is not supported after Blender 2.78c.

If you look at the [wikipedia chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_Rx_200_series#Radeon_R9_270X) for the Radeon 200 series products, you'll see that the 270 is actually a GCN 1.0 hardware. Which was dropped from Cycles in Blender 2.78c.

Comment: That is unfortunate for me to know. But I want to thank you very much for the answer since I have been struggling to know this for a long time.