# Opencl is not working on the Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E

Tags: opencl

[image]
In "Cycle Compute Divece" appears "none". It's as if I did not have a video card.
I have a board [AMD / ATI] Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E]
It is listed as having Opencl support.
This happens with both Linux (Ubuntu) and Windos (Windows 10).
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

## Your GPU is GCN 1st gen. That's why it's not supported.

Cegaton pointed out in a comment [Can't use Radeon GPU to render in cycles (R9 270)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100625/cant-use-radeon-gpu-to-render-in-cycles-r9-270)

Which is where I figured that out from this list here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units

---

EDIT: Originally I claimed and cited [that Nvidia's Cuda core programming has higher support and faster speeds](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html). However, Cegaton pointed out in the comments that as of Blender Version 2.79 OpenCL has made significant improvements. While OpenCL still is undergoing active development it appears to beat NVidia in the benchmarks, at least [in tests comparing a midrange ~$200 graphics cards](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Render/Cycles/OpenCL)

Comment: @cegaton Is that really true though? I'm only making that claim based on what I read on [Blender's official manual - What renders faster, Nvidia or AMD, CUDA or OpenCL?.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html) If you can provide some evidence of your claim I'd gladly change my answer :)

Comment: https://www.blendernation.com/2017/04/12/blender-cycles-opencl-now-par-cuda/

Comment: @cegaton I've tried to research a high end gpu comparison of Cuda vs OpenCL and found nothing so far. So in my answer I'm stating in tests comparing midrange cards, OpenCL appears to be superior. If you manage to find some more information about high end cards I'll update my answer further to include that. I noticed blender.com still states [high end cuda cards are still faster specifically.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html)